# Can I have a character that's a soul bound onto a construct, without homebrew?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, races

Is there a way to have a character who's a living construct, coming from a soul bound into a suit or a non-living construct? I'd like to use this as a player character. If there's a process by which such creatures *created,* how can I also find out about the detail on that?

In my current campaign this is what my character is, but it's homebrewed, and we may build on this in the future with new encounters, so I'd like to know if there's a way to do this without home-brewing.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of making a player character, a monster/NPC (from a GM point of view), an ally/creation (from a player point of view), or something else?

Comment: both player and gm my current character is a living construct under this premise and is home-brewed for now and i may want to make some interesting encounters in a campaign around this concept so i'd like to know if there is any known way of doing this without home-brewing

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to make a living construct with a soul bound to it, for a player character?

Comment: more or less, yes.

Comment: There are options that come immediately to mind for how to have this as a character, though I'll leave it to the actual D&D 3.5e experts to explain -- they'll no doubt be offering such suggestions in a day or two, or else I'll be setting a bounty and _then_ you'll see them. Is the process of creating one of these things via spells/rituals/whatever also an important thing for you to know about? Or is it good enough if there's just an option that says "here's how to have a soul-bound living construct character"?

Comment: having a ritual would be nice but i can just home-brew the backstory i just want to know if it's possible through actual sources .

Comment: What's the difference between a creature with the subtype living construct and what you actually want? That is, how is a warforged or an iron golem or whatever with the living construct subtype insufficient for your needs?

Comment: Before i asked this question we didn't know at the time of the warforged and we used similar ideas to the iron golem. I'm not saying it is not insufficient but since we didn't have the necessary knowledge at the time.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, I was editing this thinking warforged was _probably_ what the Warmasternick was looking for, but all signs suggested he was also completely unaware of them, or like any other genuine in-rules option for a living construct.

Comment: I only started playing this year with only one of our members who had played before and only recently got my hand's on all physical copies of the core rule books. I'm still getting a huge influx of information regarding lore,story, and mechanics. Therefore most extra content like warforged i'm still learning about.

Comment: @Warmasternick Yeah, this is a fair & good question to ask as an introduction to warforged being a thing. Many people are already aware of it, so it's kinda easy to forget there's a lot of players yet to discover them - especially new players. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener O, okay. I didn't realize someone could use the phrase *living construct* accidentally. That's cool.

Comment: @HeyICanChan well if your referring to the fact that i used living construct without knowing about warforged as doppelgreener explained.I got the idea from looking at the savage species book which had animate construct which i just made the leap to living in the sense of backstory of the character.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### This is a matter of plot, not rules, but warforged have the stats you want

In Eberron, warforged are made in Creation Forges of either Cannith or (spoilers) Quori design. The renegade mastermaker prestige class from *Magic of Eberron* details one way that a flesh-and-blood creature can become a living construct, there through literally grafting warforged components onto his or her body. This implies that it can be done.

And certainly, binding souls into constructs has a long and storied history in the sorts of narratives that D&D is based on. Nothing in Eberron, to my knowledge, actually describes such a thing taking place explicitly, and thus there are no rules for actually doing it, but it’s trivial to imagine fitting within Eberron.

So just play a warforged, but say you came about in a way that is different from other warforged. For that matter, how Creation Forges actually work is intentionally left a mystery for the DM to do with as he likes. It’s entirely possible that they are pulling souls from somewhere (most likely Dolurrh, but not necessarily). Such a character could easily have come from a Creation Forge accident. Eberron also has Eldritch Machines, literally monolithic blocks of Plot, which could certainly do this. And that’s assuming this isn’t just a grandiose variation on *trap the soul* or *magic jar* or even *reincarnate*.

I would not bother with rules for this, I would just write it into the backstory and use the warforged rules. If the actual event is to take place during the game, I would just describe the scene, and have you erase your prior racial stats and replace them with warforged.

Answer (score 1):

An Incarnate Construct from savage species may be worth looking into. Incarnate Construct is a template that can be added onto any vaguely humanoid construct. It gives them life and free will. However, it also turns them fleshy and more "human". They still keep their overall proportions, though.

Comment: there was also animate construct in there as well if i recall. it was honestly savage species that i got the idea for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking a suit (of armor, I suppose) or a golem-like body with a soul bound to it would hardly result in a living construct as a creature with named subtype. I don't know how to achieve the creature you describe without homebrew completely, but I'll try to provide method as close to actual rules as possible.

What you'll achieve will probably technically be something like permanent Shapechange into a construct (you retain your own mind, but gain all physical qualities of your new body, including type). Your DM should decide what to make you into (physical Ability Scores and Special Abilities) as well as probably set appropriate Level Adjustment or Exp fee, similar to that for becoming Necropolitan.
That last part is actually a kind of homebrew since a thing your character's soul is put into may be virtually anything artificial and generally humanoid in shape, so it's stats may vary wildly.

You should gain construct traits with following possible exceptions:

- Immunity to Mind-Affecting effects is questionable since you have your mind, but strictly by the rules, you should keep it;
- you can actually be resurrected to your normal previous form;
- your DM may want you to sleep at least sometimes, but again this isn't directly implied by the rules.

In addition to construct traits you should probably gain:

- your HD should probably change to d10's;
- low or penalised Dex, as most constructs lack in that ability;
- some Natural Weapon or Weapons (by default it is Slam, but your body may inspire different/additional ones depending on construction);
- Natural Armor or some ability that mimics worn armor;
- Damage Reduction or Hardness.

But if you want your character to be actual Living Construct (i.e. some organics included it the structure of character's body) then you should realy stick to Warforged race and ignore this answer.

Comment: not a bad answer though thank you very much :)